# How to convert wide data into long type in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have data with ID and multiple columns. I want to convert this data into a long type. And I want to remove duplicates. I want to apply his process on data with 1 Million rows is there any efficient method?

Before: 
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format?

Comment: Please don't add images of the data, add a reproducible example using `dput`. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cna use `reshape2::melt` (or the enhanced `melt` method on `data.table` objects):

```r
reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "cust_id")
```

You can also use `tidyr::pivot_longer`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
 pivot_longer(-cust_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

---

```
melt(dataframe, measure.vars = c("trans","Alt1","Alt2"), variable.name = "variable_names" , value.name = "value")
```